# Deploy Governance how to configure simple timelock from remix

Tags: openzeppelin, timelock, governance

I went to [OpenZeppelin's wizard](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard) to attempt to set up a simple token with Governance,  I'm can see examples of the token but I'm wondering what the standard deployment for a `TimelockController` is.

I have a token:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/draft-ERC20Permit.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Votes.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20, ERC20Permit, ERC20Votes {
    constructor() ERC20("MyToken", "MYT") ERC20Permit("MyToken") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    // The following functions are overrides required by Solidity.

    function _afterTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._afterTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
    }

    function _mint(address to, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._mint(to, amount);
    }

    function _burn(address account, uint256 amount)
        internal
        override(ERC20, ERC20Votes)
    {
        super._burn(account, amount);
    }
}
```

The Governance Contract also takes in a TimelockController:

```
constructor(ERC20Votes _token, TimelockController _timelock)
    Governor("MyTokenGov")
    GovernorVotes(_token)
    GovernorVotesQuorumFraction(4)
    GovernorTimelockControl(_timelock)
{}
```

I dont see in the wizard or the docs on how to setup and configure a `TimelockController`.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Kinda, basically I just watch some tutorial that chainlink putout on governance and they configure the whole thing